# Genius GX Gila Mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse, games

So I have a Genius GX Gila gaming mouse. It doesn't work.
Having previously had Arch installed and running various troubleshooting steps I came to the conclusion that Linux detects it as a Keyboard. 
The mouse has various macro keys which I would hazard a guess at being picked up as the keyboard component.
Now I'm not too fussed about getting those to work in Ubuntu but it would be nice to operate it simply as a mouse.

This is the output of lsusb.

```
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0716 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Multislot Card Reader/Writer
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:0a0b Logitech, Inc. ClearChat Pro USB
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
**Bus 007 Device 004: ID 0458:0138 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems)** 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Its the KYE Systems Corp. line.

This is a snippet of dmesg.

```
[ 1019.332966] input: Genius Gila Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-3/7-3:1.1/input/input17
[ 1019.333236] hid-generic 0003:0458:0138.000B: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Genius Gila Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:16.0-3/input1
[ 1019.338725] hid-generic 0003:0458:0138.000C: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [Genius Gila Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:16.0-3/input2
```

As you can see it thinks it's a keyboard. 
I have found a similar problem with a Sharkoon Drakonia which someone on Arch managed to fix by substituting the device ID into X's input file. 
This however seems to have me stumped and I cannot find out how to this, if anyone could advise I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1741137?do=post_view_flat) is a patch . You may try applying it or wait until it is included into the mainline Kernel.

Comment: Could you please explain how one could apply that patch?

Comment: You need to rebuild kernel.
Before rebuilding, perform 
cd <kernel source root dir> 
and then
git apply /path/to/patch